# Ajax Request Fails why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

following my code:

```
    $('#btnOK').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $form = $('#testForm');
        dataString = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://abc.com/login',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function( returnData ) {
                alert(returnData);
            }
        });
    });
```

My Code fails to make ajax request to http://abc.com/login page and doesn't gives out result. What's the mistake here?

Is it due to cross domain likely:
my domain: http://xyz.com
login domain: http://abc.com/login

Comment: Just a look at error console would tell you exact source of error

Comment: You answered your own question: [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Yes, It is due to cross domain, you can't send ajax request to a different domain for security reason.

Comment: Why down vote? He just want to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless your `abc.com` domain is configured to deal with cross-origin policy, you won't be able to make a cross-domain ajax call

A solution is to redirect your ajax call to a server side proxy under `xyz.com` domain who send your data and get the response from `abc.com` (e.g. using `CURL`).

or if you're in control of `abc.com` domain you could send proper headers ([Access-Control-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#The_HTTP_request_headers)) to allow crossdomain calls

Answer (score 1):

my domain: http://xyz.com
login domain: http://abc.com/login

This is cross domain issue you can get over with

1. Proxy on your site
2. JsonP support from abc.com site
3. If you just want to post and dont care what result is, you can create a form and a iframe then set target of the form to that iframe, then just post (wont work with csrf enabled site)

Answer (score 0):

Just debug it use chrome or ie debugger, make a breakpoint at the entry of the click() function, and then step by step, you'll find the problem.